# How to estimate statistical significance of the difference between two groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, mean

I need to be sure that the difference between estimations of the percent of returning visitors to a web page in two groups is not just a random difference. I have the following data:

```
       Group 1     Group 2
Day 1  2.0%        2.2%
Day 2  1.8%        2.1%
...
Day 5  2.1%        1.5%
```

For example, there is 2.0% of persons who have returned to a web-site on Day 1 (which means that a person visited the website more than 1 time during the day).
How can I evaluate the statistical significance of the difference between Group 1 and Group 2? Do I need more that 5 days of observations, or can I extract some conclusions based on these 5 days?
The size of Group 1 and Group 2 is 10000 and 12000, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to test if your model matches the parameters of a t-test, if so, the easy way is to go for a T-Test against the null hypotheses of both distributions being the same.

If your populations do not match the parameters of normalit`y and homocedasticity (similar variances between both datasets) you will have to go for a non-parametric alternative, here you have an even higher number of options, Wilcoxon's test, or Friedman's are quite standard and generally, well accepted in the academic community.

You can extract some conclussions with only 5 samples? Sure you can, but you have to question yourself if the sample is representative for your problem, probably for a problem involving active users, a 5-day scope is a little limited, consider using a bigger scope